# how to query with child relations to same table and order this correctly

Tags: sql, mysql

Take this table:

```
id      name      sub_id
---------------------------
1        A        (null)
2        B        (null)
3        A2       1
4        A3       1
```

The sub_id column is a relation to his own table, to column ID.

```
 subid --- 0:1  --- id
```

Now I have the problem to make a correctly SELECT query to show that the child rows (which sub_id is not null) directly selected under his parent row. So this must be a correctly order:

```
1    A    (null)
3    A2   1
4    A3   1
2    B    (null)
```

A normal SELECT order the id. But how or which keyword help me to order this correctly?

JOIN isn't possible I think because I want to get all the rows separated. Because the rows will be displayed on a Gridview (ASP.Net) with EntityDataSource but the child rows must be displayed directly under his parent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Since recursion is an expensive operation because basicly you're firing multiple queries to your database you could consider using the Nested Set Model. In short you're assigning numbers to ranges in your table. It's a long article but it worth reading it. I've used it during my internship as a solution not to have 1000+ queries, But bring it down to 1 query.

Your handling 'overhead' now lies at the point of updating the table by adding, updating or deleting records. Since you then have to update all the records with a bigger 'right-value'. But when you're retrieving the data, it all goes with 1 query :)

Comment: @Ben: I have no time to read this article right now but will surely go through it. Till now I use CTE to solve this problem which uses recursion as its basic concept. +1 from my side.

Comment: @Ben: I was reading the article, I need to know whether it works in those scenario where depth of the tree is not known previously and tree can go up to any depth as the user inserts some records in it.

Comment: Yes it does, refering to this image in the article: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-4.png. If you want to create a deeper level you will have to update the left en right values of all entries after your latest insert.

Comment: @Ben, Good advice about using Nested Set Model. Thank you for your information and website.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table1 order by name, sub_id` will in this case return your desired result but only because the parents names and the child name are similar. If you're using SQL 2005 a recursive CTE will work:

```
WITH recurse (id, Name, childID, Depth)
AS
(
    SELECT id, Name, ISNULL(childID, id) as id, 0 AS Depth
    FROM table1 where childid is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT table1.id, table1.Name, table1.childID, recurse.Depth + 1 AS Depth FROM table1
    JOIN recurse ON table1.childid = recurse.id
)

SELECT * FROM recurse order by childid, depth
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But ordering on name is not the solution because in real, the names are different. I'm sorry. Database is Mysql so recursing isn't a solution.

Comment: You could use a recursive function in your programming language (eg. PHP) which executes 1 query at a time. But therefore i prefer my answer, posted below.

Comment: Ok since it mysql you probably want to check out Ben's answer

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
   * 
 FROM 
   table
 ORDER BY
   COALESCE(id,sub_id), id

btw, this will work only for one level.. any thing more than that requires recursive/cte function